Calculate this limit using integral
Giving $a$, $b$ are two positive numbers and $\alpha$ is a positive integer; calculate the limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{1}{n^{2\alpha+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k^2+ak+b\right)^{\alpha}\right]
$$
I think Riemann integral will be useful for this.
$$
\mbox{But how to make it in the form}\quad
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{f}\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)\ ?.
$$
Please give me a hint.

@AnneBauval, Not as elegant as I originally envisioned, but I added my own take to this problem.

Besides Riemann, you can use Stolz-Ces${\rm\grave a}!$ro Theorem.

Intuition. Write the sum as
$$ S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n}\biggl( \underbrace{\frac{k^2}{n^2} + \frac{ak}{n^2} + \frac{b}{n^2}}_{=: x_{n,k}} \biggr)^{\alpha} \frac{1}{n}. $$
Then intuitively, for large $n$, $x_{n,k}$ will be close to $\frac{k^2}{n^2}$, hence the above sum behaves like
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\biggl( \frac{k^2}{n^2}\biggr)^{\alpha} \frac{1}{n} \to \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2\alpha + 1}. $$
Rigorous Proof. Choose a positive integer $m$ such that $\max\{\tfrac{1}{2}|a|, \sqrt{|b|}\} \leq m$. Then for any $k$,
$$ x_{n,k} = \frac{k^2 + ak + b}{n^2} \leq \frac{k^2 + 2mk + m^2}{n^2} = \left(\frac{k+m}{n}\right)^2. $$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
S_n
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k+m}{n} \right)^{2\alpha} \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^{2\alpha} \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{2\alpha} - \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^{2\alpha}}{n} \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^{2\alpha} \frac{1}{n} + \frac{C}{n}
\end{align*}
for some constant $C$. This gives
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n \leq \int_{0}^{1} x^{2\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
A similar argument shows that
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n \geq \int_{0}^{1} x^{2\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}x, $$
hence the desired concolusion follows.

We can generalize the question by assuming $\alpha$ is a positive real number (not necessarily an integer). First rewrite the $n$th term of your sequence as a Riemann sum of
the function
$$f_n(x):=\left(x^2+\frac anx+\frac b{n^2}\right)^\alpha:$$
$$\frac1{n^{2\alpha+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k^2+ak+b\right)^\alpha=S_n:=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf_n\left(\frac kn\right).$$
Since $f_n$
is increasing on $[0,1]$, its integral stands between $S_n$
and
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f_n\left(\frac kn\right)=S_n+\frac{f_n(0)-f_n(1)}n.$$
Therefore (since the sequence $\left(f_n(0)-f_n(1)\right)$ is bounded)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1x^{2\alpha}dx=\frac1{2\alpha+1}.$$
The interchange of limit and integral can be justified for instance by the dominated convergence theorem, or more elementarily by proving explicitely the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ on $[0,1]$:

if $\alpha\le1$, $f_n(x)-x^{2\alpha}\le\left(\frac anx+\frac b{n^2}\right)^\alpha\le\left(\frac{a+b}n\right)^\alpha$
if $\alpha\ge1$, $f_n(x)-x^{2\alpha}\le\alpha\left(x^2+\frac anx+\frac b{n^2}\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(\frac anx+\frac b{n^2}\right)\le\alpha\left(1+a+b\right)^{\alpha-1}\;\frac{a+b}n$.

